# Visual Studio Code unable to set env variable paths prior to debugging python file

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I have a python project I need to debug

It comes with its own python installation, lets say in `c:\project\python.exe` and libraries, located in `c:\project\libraries\..`

It's launched with a cmd file `C:\project\start.cmd`

The cmd file executes another file called `c:\projects\setenv.cmd` which sets up paths to each library while the prompt is open

I'm trying to replicate this functionality in Visual Studio Code

I created a workspace and set it up so the following files are in the workspace `.vscode` folder:

settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\project\\python.exe"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "preLaunchTask": "shellCommand",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "shellCommand",
            "command": "C:\\project\\set_env.cmd ; pause",
            "type": "shell"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I open the `main.py` file which the `start.cmd` executes after `setenv.cmd`, and start debugging,

I can see that the task `shellCommand` is executed and the `setenv.cmd` runs, because of the pause statement.

The output I get is below:

```
C:\project>SET PYTHONPATH=C:\project\libraries\camera;C:\project\libraries\exewrappers
Press Enter to continue...:
```

However, the `main.py` file crashes on the first library import, which it cannot find

The library path is correct, but it seems that Visual Studio Code forgets the Path variable after `setenv.cmd` is executed

How can I make it so the env variables set up by `setenv.cmd` are still remembered when I'm debugging the `main.py` file?