# Cannot set pythonpath environment variable from python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm trying to debug a project that has a lot of additional libraries added to PYTHONPATH at runtime before launching the python file.

I was not able to add those commands with `tasks.json` file prior to debugging python file in Visual Studio code (see post [Visual Studio Code unable to set env variable paths prior to debugging python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239351/visual-studio-code-unable-to-set-env-variable-paths-prior-to-debugging-python-fi)), so I'm just adding them via an `os.system("..")` command

I'm only showing 1 of the libraries added below:

```
# Standard library imports
import os
import sys

os.system("SET PYTHONPATH=D:\\project\\calibration\\pylibrary\\camera")

# Pylibrary imports
from camera import capture
```

When I debug, it fails on line `from camera import capture` with:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'camera'
  File "D:\project\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from camera.capture import capture
```

I also tried

`os.environ['PYTHONPATH']="D:\\project\\pylibrary\\camera"` and I still get the same error

Why is it not remembering the `pythonpath` while running the script?

How else can I define the `pythonpath` while running Visual Studio Code and debugging the project file?

I know I can add the `pythonpath` to env variables in windows, but it loads too many libraries and I want it to only remember the path while the python script is executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.system()` won't work because it starts a new cmd.exe shell and sets the env var in that shell. That won't affect the env vars of the python process. Assigning to `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` won't work because at that point your python process has already cached the value, if any, of that env var in the `sys.path` variable. The solution is to

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"D:\project\calibration\pylibrary\camera")
```